# System.Drawing alternative in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml, stream

Hi I am running into a small problem with loading a Bitmap image from a wcf rest service:

```
    public Image GetImage(int width, int height)
    {
        string uri = string.Format("http://localhost:8000/Service/picture/{0}/{1}", width, height);
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);

        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                return new Bitmap(stream); //no System.Drawing.Bitmap class in wpf?
            }
        }
    }
```

Seems there is no System.Drawing class for wpf so how can I fix this? Another problem related to this is how do I set the source:

```
image1.Source = GetImage(image1.Height, image1.Width); //best overload for this line
// also not sure if source would be correct?
```

In windows forms you can do this:

```
pictureBox1.Image = GetImage(pictureBox1.Height, pictureBox1.Width);
```

Which works fine but wpf obviously has to annoy me to no end!

Im really hoping there is something simple that can be done here?

```
        <GroupBox Height="141" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="groupBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="141" BorderBrush="#FFA3A3A3" Background="#37000000" Margin="1,21,0,0">
            <Image Name="image1" Stretch="Fill"/>
        </GroupBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF shouldn't annoy you.  It's even easier.

```
    <GroupBox Height={Binding Height}" Width="{Binding Width"}>
        <Image Source="{Binding MyImageUrl}" />
    </GroupBox>
```

Your view model could be something like

```
public class ImageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    public string ImageUrl
    {
        get
        {
            return "your url here";
        }
    }

    public double Width
    {
        get { return "required width"; }
    }

    public double Height
    {
        get { return "required height"; }
    }
}
```

and of course you would need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: thats nice but... `("http://localhost:8000/Service/picture/{0}/{1}", width, height)` my webservice takes a value on the GET request of the image height and width. Those need to be set by the image container which I have manually configured.